# Steam missing 32 bit libraries libx11-6

Tags: debian, steam

I tried to install Steam and some libraries were missing:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libX11.so.6

I could install each one except this libX11.so.6.

```
$ sudo apt install libx11-6
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
libx11-6 ist schon die neueste Version (2:1.6.4-3+deb9u1).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 7 nicht aktualisiert
```

The error of title of this question persists. How can I find this libX11.so.6 to play on Steam?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable the `i386` architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

Then install the 32-bit package:

```
sudo apt install libx11-6:i386
```